# In what ways can Shakespeare's Pericles, Prince of Tyre be classified as a typical romance play?

Tags: william-shakespeare, pericles-prince-of-tyre

In what ways can Shakespeare's *Pericles, Prince of Tyre* be classified as a typical romance play?

Comment: Why is this question being flagged to be closed? It's a decent question, and there are clear elements of a "typical romance play". Just because the question is short doesn't make it bad, no less in need of being closed.

Answer (score 2):

The romances is a category of Shakespeare's plays that includes *Pericles*, *Cymbeline*, *The Winter's Tale* and *The Tempeest*.
*The Two Noble Kinsmen* is sometimes also included into this category, even though it has less in common with Shakespeare's "canonical" romances.

- **Courtly versus pastoral scenes** (Schmidgall: *Shakespeare and the Courtly Aesthetic*, 1981, cited on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shakespeare%27s_late_romances#Defining_characteristics)):

  - *Pericles*: There are scenes at court, but the pastoral is not really represented in the play.
  - *Cymbeline*: Cymbeline's court versus the cave in Wales where Guiderius and Arviragus grew up.
  - *The Winter's Tale*: Act 4, scenes 2-4 are pastoral, especially the sheep-shearing feast Act 4, scene 4. The other scenes are set at Leontes's court in Sicily.
  - *The Tempest*: Alonso and his courtiers versus the island's residents. See also Gonzalo's speech about a kind of utopia in Act 2, scene 1.
  - Note that this is not a new motif, since Shakespeare also used it in *As You Like It*.
- **"Older men are more prominently featured"** (Wikipedia, citing Bieman's *William Shakespeare: The Romances*). I consider this characteristic questionable for the reasons given below:

  - *Pericles*: Pericles is still a young Prince at the beginning of the play.
  - *Cymbeline*: Cymbeline may be considered "old"; his sons Guiderius and Arvirargus were kidnapped twenty years before the events of the play. However, he is not as prominent in the play as Prospero in *The Tempest*.
  - *The Winter's Tale*: Leontes is hardly "old" at the beginnig of the play; his son Mamilius is still a child and his wife Hermione is pregnant.
  - *The Tempest*: Prospero is usually represented as old, even though his daughter Miranda is still a teenager.
- **"The presence of pre-Christian, masque-like figures"** (Wikipedia, citing A. L. Rowse's *The Annotated Shakespeare: Volume III*):

  - *Pericles*: The Roman goddess Diana appears to Pericles in a dream.
  - *Cymbeline*: The Roman god Jupiter appears to Cymbeline.
  - *The Winter's Tale*: The Oracle at Delphos (Act 3).
  - *The Tempest*: Iris, Juno and Ceres in Act 4, scene 1.
- A **long time gap** between two parts of the play:

  - *Pericles*: Many years pass between the first three acts (or the first 14 scenes) and the remainder of the play; based on Pericles's story in Act 5, scene 3 (or scene 23), fourteen years have passed since he lost his wife Thaisa.
  - *Cymbeline*: No, but twenty years have passed between the abduction of Cymbeline's sons Guiderius and Arviragus and the events in the play (see Act 3, scene 3).
  - *The Winter's Tale*: In Act 4, scene 1, the figure of Time tells us that sixteen years pass between the the end of Act3 and the remainder of the play (Act 4 and 5).
  - *The Tempest*: No, but there is a 12-year gap between Prospero and Miranda's shipwreck (related in Act 1, scene 2) and the beginning of the play.
- **Family members believed dead**:

  - *Pericles*: In Act 3, scene 1, Pericles's wife Thaisa seems to die in childbirth. In Act 4, scene 1, (or scene 15) Marina is kidnapped by pirates; in Act 4, scene 4 (or scene 18) Pericles is made to believe that his daughter is dead.
  - *Cymbeline*: In Act 4, scene 2, Guiderius and Arviragus believe Innogen/Fidele is dead. When Innogen wakes up, she thinks she sees Posthumus's corpse (it is really the headless body of Cloten, who had disguised himself as Posthumus).
  - *The Winter's Tale*: Leontes believes his wife Hermione has died (Act 3, scene 1).
  - *The Tempest*: After being separated by the storm, Alonso and his son Ferdinand both assume the other dead. (See e.g. "Full fathom five" in Act 1, scene 2.)
  - Note that this is not a new motif, since Shakespeare also used it in *Twelfth Night* (Viola thinks her brother Sebastian has drowned).
- **Forced separations and improbable reunions** (Dobson & Wells, page 395):

  - *Pericles*: See "Family members believed dead". Pericles is reunited with Marina in Act 5, scene 1 (or scene 21) and with Thaisa in Act 5, scene 3 (or scene 23).
  - *Cymbeline*: Innogen has married the commoner Posthumus, who is banished in Act 1, scene 1.
  - *The Winter's Tale*: Leontes and Perdita, Leontes and Hermione; to a lesser extent Leontes and Polixenes.
  - *The Tempest*: After the storm, Alonso and his courtiers land on a different part of the island than Alonso's son Sebastian.
- **Father-daughter relationships** (Dobson & Wells, page 395):

  - *Pericles*: Pericles and Marina.
  - *Cymbeline*: Cymbeline and Innogen.
  - *The Winter's Tale*: Leontes and Perdita.
  - *The Tempest*: Prospero and Miranda.
  - Note that this is not a new motif, since Shakespeare also used it in *King Lear* (Lear and his daughers), *Hamlet* (Polonius and Ophelia) and *The Merchant of Venice* (Shylock and Jessica), for example.
- **Shipwreck at sea** (Dobson & Wells, page 395):

  - *Pericles*: In Act 1, scene 4, Pericles suffers shipwreck near Persepolis. In Act 3, scene 1, there is another storm.
  - *Cymbeline*: No scenes at sea, nor a shipwreck.
  - *The Winter's Tale*: The ship that brought Antigonus to Bohemia is wrecked by a storm in Act 3, scene 3.
  - *The Tempest*: The ship that is taking Alonso, King of Naples, back to Italy is caught in a storm and runs aground in Act 1, scene 1.
  - Note that this is not a new motif, since Shakespeare also used it in *The Comedy of Errors* and *Twelfth Night*.

According to Constance Jordan, the four plays have a common subject: **"the restoration of good government"** (page 1):

> The plays depict the precarious state of rulers who by their absence invite anarchy or by their presumption threaten tyranny. These rules stand decisively apart from their subjects. (...)
> Chastened by various trials, Pericles, Cymbeline, Leontes, and Prospero submit at last to the constraints that attend mortality.

---

**Sources**:

- Dobson, Michael; Wells, Stanley (editors): *The Oxford Companion to Shakespeare*. Oxford University Press, 2001.
- Jordan, Constance: *Shakespeare's Monarchies: Ruler and Subject in the Romances*. Cornell University Press, 1997.